# How can I attach the scroll function to the views in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

This is what I am doing in the controller.

```
onAfterRendering: function(){ 
   this.getView().attachBrowserEvent("window.onscroll", function(){ 
        alert('scrolled'); 
   }); 
}
```

It does nothing. Want to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496436/why-scroll-event-not-working-in-ui5-sap-m-page

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use a scroll container instead of event if that is your requirement, look at the link below for api

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ScrollContainer

example

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.ScrollContainer/code

You can put n number of content in the scroll container.

Hope this helps.